# Evaulating if-statements in React using State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been having issues with if statements correctly evaluating, either always showing true or exhibiting strange behavior when passing variables or using state variables to be evaluated. I understand this may be an issue with different objects or the asynchronous nature of setState but I'm not really sure /how/ it works. 
 
Hoping to get help understanding how to get this to evaluate correctly, if any extra code is needed I'll add on but this should hopefully cover all that is needed for this example of my overall form validation.

**State**

```
constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = 
        {
            newProfile: 
            {
                name: '',
                email: '',
                gender: '',
                userType: '',
                password: ''        
            },

            match: true,
            formValid: false,
            nameValid: false,
            emailValid: false,
            genderSelectionValid: false,
            userTypeValid: false,
            passwordValid: false,

            formErrors: 
            {
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                gender: '',
                userType: ''
            },

            passwordConfirm: '',

            profileOptions: ['Investor', 'Student'],
            genderOptions: ['Male','Female','Other'],

            first: true
        };
        this.handleGenderChange = this.handleGenderChange.bind(this);
        this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSecondPasswordChange = this.handleSecondPasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.handleUserTypeChange = this.handleUserTypeChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFormSubmission = this.handleFormSubmission.bind(this);
        this.validateName = this.validateName.bind(this);
        this.validateForm = this.validateForm.bind(this);
    }
```

**Form Selection**

```
            <Select options = {this.state.genderOptions}
                    placeholder = {'Select Gender'}
                    handleChange = {this.handleGenderChange}
                    title = {'Gender'}
            />
```

**Form Selection jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const Select = (props) =>
{
    return(
        <div className='form-group'>
            <label> {props.title} </label>
            <select
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.handleChange}>
                required
                <option>{props.placeholder}</option>
                {props.options.map(field => 
                { return(
                    <option
                        key={field}
                        value={field}
                        label={field}>{field}
                    </option>
                    );
                    })}
            </select>
        </div>)
}

export default Select;
```

**Button handler for this example**

```
    handleGenderChange(event)
    {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        let value = event.target.value;
        let tempProfile = this.state.newProfile;
        tempProfile.gender = value;
        this.setState({newProfile: tempProfile});
        console.log(this.state.newProfile.gender);
        this.validateGenderSelection(value);
    }
```

**validateGenderSelection**

```
validateGenderSelection(gender)
    {
        let localFormErrors = this.state.formErrors;

        if(gender == "Male" || "Female" || "Other")
        {
            localFormErrors.gender = "";
            this.setState({genderSelectionValid: true});
        }
        else
        {
            localFormErrors.gender = "No gender selected.";
            this.setState({genderSelectionValid: false});
        }
        this.setState({formErrors: localFormErrors});
        this.validateForm();
    }
```

**Overall Form Validation**

```
    validateForm()
    {
        if(this.state.nameValid === true && this.state.emailValid === true && this.state.passwordValid === true && this.state.userTypeValid === true && this.state.genderSelectionValid === true)
        {
        this.setState({formValid: true});
        }
        if(this.state.formValid === false)
        {
            console.log(this.state.formErrors);
        }
        console.log(this.state.newProfile.gender);
        console.log(this.state.nameValid, this.state.emailValid, this.state.genderSelectionValid, this.state.userTypeValid, this.state.passwordValid, this.state.formValid);
    }
```

Comment: You didn't declare `this.state.genderValid` anywhere in your code, therefore it's not truthy (it's undefined) and the test fails. Wasn't it supposed to be `this.state.genderSelectionValid`?

Comment: It is, I've gone ahead and updated that. formValid now updates correctly, though validateGenderSelection isn't working as intended. For the first selection it will stay false, but if you select another, as well as the "Select Gender" placeholder it will shift to true and stay there no matter what is selected. Thanks for that particular fix though! I can't believe I had that sort of oversight

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` is async and are batched on regular functions like these...

Use this to check how many times component updated

```
    componentDidUpdate() {
      console.log('update', this.state);
    }
```

In order to make your work

```
validateGenderSelection(gender)
    {
        let localFormErrors = {...this.state.formErrors};

        if(gender == "Male" ||gender == "Female" || gender =="Other")
        {
            localFormErrors.gender = true;
            this.setState({genderSelectionValid: true});
        }
        else
        {
            localFormErrors.gender = "No gender selected.";
            this.setState({genderSelectionValid: false});
        }
        this.setState({formErrors: localFormErrors}, this.validateForm);
    }
    validateForm()
    {
        if(this.state.nameValid === true && this.state.emailValid === true && this.state.passwordValid === true && this.state.userTypeValid === true && this.state.genderSelectionValid === true)
        {
        this.setState({formValid: true});
        }
        if(this.state.formValid === false)
        {
            console.log('this.state.formErrors', this.state.formErrors);
        }
        console.log(this.state.newProfile.gender);
        console.log(this.state.nameValid, this.state.emailValid, this.state.genderSelectionValid, this.state.userTypeValid, this.state.passwordValid, this.state.formValid);
    }
```

Besides, why are maintaining too many states for each and every value...I think you could make the state better and clean

Comment: What would you suggest for cleaning up state? Some auxiliary functions?

Comment: It now switches to true for when I select a valid gender for the first time, but if the user selects the placeholder text "Select Gender" again it doesn't swap to false.
I made it so it cannot be selected again, ignore this, thanks!

Comment: I think it switched to false on `select gender`... https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-driscoll-g0v9p..

Comment: I think you don't need 3 different state value to store and validate a single form object...